# Extract $bitmap file from NTFS Image

Tags: ntfs

Does anyone know of any software that can extract the `$bitmap` file from NTFS images?

Or does anyone know of any site that documents NTFS enough so that I can code this myself?

(I want to read the `$bitmap` so I can identify what clusters are not in use, so they can be removed from the images.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dump the NTFS $Bitmap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310120/how-to-dump-the-ntfs-bitmap-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one short paragraph in this early publication by a talented person:

http://www.alex-ionescu.com/NTFS.pdf

Comment: I also found this: data.linux-ntfs.org/ntfsdoc.pdf which should be enough info to do it myself.

Comment: Mirrors found at http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf and http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/ntfsofuefi/NTFS%20Reference%20Documents/ntfsdoc.pdf might disappear in the future too.  Grab your copy today.

Comment: The Wayback Machine has Alex Ionescu's original: http://web.archive.org/web/20110124171746/http://www.alex-ionescu.com/NTFS.pdf

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is also "*Forensic File Systems*" by Brian Carrier. It does explain NTFS in detail.
[ntfs.org](http://ntfs.org/) also is helpful.

Since `$Bitmap` is a system file, you can't open it up and read it. Also beware that if the disk is in use, it can change.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this one in a different place, but on a live Windows machine the best answer is probably to use [FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364573(VS.85).aspx).  This will reflect any changes the FS knows about that aren't on the disk.

Comment: Can you add some stuff from the link?