# How can I view a dump of a NTFS $Logfile?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, storage, ntfs, data-recovery

I recently encountered a strange Windows 7 bug where a 600 MB video file I spent ~1 hour recording disappeared with no trace. I've tried using applications such as Recuva to see if I can recover it to no avail.

I know for sure that the file existed at one point because there is still a link to its location in VLC Media player's history. That said, there SHOULD be a reference to the data write operations in the NTFS $LogFile on the volume where this file was created. Whenever I try to do a 'type $Logfile' or open it through an application I get "Access is Denied". I am logged in as an account with Local Administrator privileges.

Does anyone know a surefire method of viewing the NTFS $LogFile for a given volume?

Comment: Did you figure out how to dump $LogFile. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

nfi.exe should help. take a look at the following question:

[How to dump the NTFS $Bitmap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310120/how-to-dump-the-ntfs-bitmap-file/10329233#10329233)

Answer (score 0):

Try fget or ntfs opt, see here:
http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2011/10/how-to-acquire-locked-files-from.html